# Using Apple's Create ML algorithms

Tags: xcode, createml

I want to use Apple's Create ML for the first time.

I have been reading every where to find how to specify the algorithm I should use but could not find any training or document mention using algorithms in Apple's Create ML

Is Create ML is a form of AutoML that it search by itself for the best algorithm that gives the highest accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start Create ML, it asks you to choose a template, based on your goal and data type. That is how it selects an algorithm.